# Where does the Apple Workout app "save" completed workouts?

Tags: apple-watch

The Apple Watch Workout app offers an option to "Save" a workout when it has been completed. Where are such saved workouts saved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can view all your past workouts (per day) on the iPhone Activity app! It gives you all the same information you see when you save the workout on your watch.

You can also view past workouts in the Health app (Workouts data in the Fitness section).

Comment: I'd like to see the individual workouts that I saved.  In particular, I'm looking to see "how many minutes was that workout I did after lunch?", but without it being combined with my morning workout.  Activity seems to just give the day's totals.

Comment: No the Activate app on the iPhone doesn't show you anything other than minutes, so it doesn't give you "all the same information". The Health app will give you (rough) steps/walking/running distances, but not your workout times. The Apple Watch fitness app, brought to you by people who have never worked out before, and think "save" means "please forever hide my workout distance/times".

Answer (score 2):

The Activity app on your iPhone has it (iOS 10 & watchOS 3).

1. Open Activity on your iPhone
2. Browse to the day
3. Hit workouts at the bottom
4. Select the workout

For my Indoor Run, it has the type, time, active & total calories, distance, total time, average heart rate and average pace (also split out by mile).  Doesn't have maximum heart rate, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Health app go to health data at the bottom and scroll down to workouts. You can add them to your dashboard from there or just tap show all data and it's in there.
If you add them to dashboard when you click the graph it has individual workout details.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the Health app, and go to "Workouts" - you can click on that graph and go to "show all data" - and it will give you all the specifics on each of your watch workouts.